# FileUtils.readFileToString() from Apache Commons IO works incorrectly with Cyrillic

Tags: java, encoding, cyrillic, fileutils

I am using FileUtils.readFileToString to read contents of a text file with JSON at once. The file is UTF-8 encoded (w/o BOM). Yet, instead of cyrillic letters I get ?????? signs. Why?

```
public String getJSON() throws IOException
{
    File customersFile = new File(this.STORAGE_FILE_PATH);
    return FileUtils.readFileToString(customersFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: Where do you see ??? instead of cyrilic? Console? IDE? Other file?

Comment: @StephaneM that question should have basically answered his question :D

Comment: @StephaneM I have built a small REST service using Spring Framework. ????s are returned in response for GET request. Yet they are only in place of cyrillic letters.

Comment: You don't answer my question. Where do you read the response of your GET request?

Comment: @StephaneM In any place where I can make GET request: from a browser, from a Javascript console, from a Python console.

Comment: It looks like this: {"lastName":"??????","phone":"77777777777","email":"test@example.com","address":"??????","secondName":"???????","firstName":"???????","city":"??????"}

Comment: And does the font in the browser have glyphs for cyrillic chars (and encoding set to UTF-8)?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Yes, it does.

Comment: What is the encoding of the REST response? You need to examine every and all places where strings are converted to/from bytes: reading the file on server, sending data from server to client, saving data on client, viewing data on client.

Answer (score 0):

`FileUtils.readFileToString` doesn't work with `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Instead, try

`FileUtils.readFileToString(customersFile, "UTF-8");`

or

`FileUtils.readFileToString(customersFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());`

Comment: Well, there is a variant of `FileUtils.readFileToString` which accepts `Charset`, so why not `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`? I have solved the problem another way long ago, but in my free time I'll maybe take a look again.

Comment: Agree with @MikhailBatcer , see https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it back in 2015:

```
public String getJSON() throws IOException
{
//    File customersFile = new File(this.STORAGE_FILE_PATH);
//    return FileUtils.readFileToString(customersFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String JSON = "";
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(this.STORAGE_FILE_PATH);
    String nextString = "";
    try {
        if (stream != null) {
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            while ((nextString = reader.readLine()) != null)
                JSON = new StringBuilder().append(JSON).append(nextString).toString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return JSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in logs all was fine, so I solved problem in rest controller:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/getXmlByIin", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```